# 1052: Column 'memberID' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables: blog_posts & blog_members. I want to select the postStatus entity from blog_posts through using innerjoin. But i always get this error: **Column 'memberID' in field list is ambiguous**

**memberID is a FK in blog_posts.**

This is my query.

```
 $stmt = $db->query('SELECT memberID, username, email, status, date_joined, blog_posts.postStatus FROM blog_members INNER JOIN blog_posts ON blog_members.memberID = blog_posts.memberID WHERE status != "admin1" ORDER BY date_joined DESC');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify which table `memberID` is coming from, even if it is equal int he two tables due to the join condition:

```
SELECT blog_members.memberID,  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have the column memberID in more than one table, so you need to be explicit about which table you want to get the value from, e.g.:

`SELECT blog_posts.memberID...`